# Implement Android Navigation Component with Flexible Space Pattern aka Collapsing Toolbar

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, bottomnavigationview, android-architecture-navigation

I am starting to work on Android application and I would like to use this new Android navigation component. And this application will have bottom navigation view with 5 sections, and each of those sections needs to keep backstack of fragments. Like if I am on First Section and navigate to search results and then navigate to map, and now if I click on profile section in bottom navigation view then return to first section I still need to be at the map screen. So I found this [medium article](https://proandroiddev.com/mastering-the-bottom-navigation-with-the-new-navigation-architecture-component-cd6a71b266ae) that explains one possible solution to this problem which is to have 5 NavHostFragments and you show/hide them based on which section you are. Also another thing is that when you navigate to some fragments I need to hide bottom navigation view... So I created new project to try some things out and I got some strange results. I can't fully understand how `fitsSystemWindows` attribute work and I got some weird behaviors...

[image: problem]

First thing is that the title in the toolbar at the 4th image has some top margin and I have no idea why... I have created completely new project without fragments, just one main activity with exact same layout and I don't have top margin for title in toolbar.

The second thing is that when I get back from Safari page to search results (4th and 5th images), bottom navigation view is half visible for no reason...

How do I fix 4th and 5th images?
Also one more question regarding `fitSystemWindows` attribute. Shouldn't Search button on the first image be under the status bar? Since `fitSystemWindows=true` is not applied on `ConstraintLayout -> FrameLayout -> ExploreFragment's ConstraintLayout`. The only place where `fitSystemWindows` attribute is added to XML is in `fragment_safari.xml` file.

**Note**: Minimum Android API level that I need to support is 21 (Lollipop and above).

Here is the code:

**Theme that I am using**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorWindowBackground</item>
</style>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    // ...

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        currentController = findNavController(R.id.explore_nav_host_fragment)

        exploreNavController.addOnNavigatedListener { controller, destination ->
            when (destination.id) {
                R.id.searchResultsFragment,
                R.id.exploreFragment -> showBottomNavigation()
                R.id.safariFragment,
                R.id.filterFragment -> hideBottomNavigation()
            }
        }

        bottom_navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            when (it.itemId) {
                R.id.action_explore -> {
                    currentController = exploreNavController
                    explore_nav_host_frame.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    favorite_nav_host_frame.visibility = View.GONE
                    reviews_nav_host_frame.visibility = View.GONE
                    true
                }
                R.id.action_favorite -> {
                    currentController = favoriteNavController
                    explore_nav_host_frame.visibility = View.GONE
                    favorite_nav_host_frame.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    reviews_nav_host_frame.visibility = View.GONE
                    true
                }
                else -> false
            }
        }
    }

    fun hideBottomNavigation() {
        if(isBottomNavigationViewVisible) {
            bottom_navigation.visibility = View.GONE
            isBottomNavigationViewVisible = false
        }
    }

    fun showBottomNavigation() {
        if(!isBottomNavigationViewVisible) {
            bottom_navigation.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            isBottomNavigationViewVisible = true
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/explore_nav_host_frame"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/explore_nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="false"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph_explore" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/favorite_nav_host_frame"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/favorite_nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="false"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph_favorite" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/reviews_nav_host_frame"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/reviews_nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="false"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph_reviews" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**SafariFragment.kt**

```
class SafariFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_safari, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        initActionBar()
        addTextViews()
    }

    private fun initActionBar() {
        (activity as AppCompatActivity).apply {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
            supportActionBar?.apply {
                title = "Safari"
                setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
                setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun addTextViews() {
        for(i in 1..10) {
            content_scroll.addView(TextView(context).apply {
                text = i.toString()
                setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorAccent))
                setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white))
                layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    48*3
                ).apply {
                    setMargins(36, 36, 36, 36)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

**fragment_safari.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed|snap">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/safari_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/safari"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:background="@drawable/toolbar_gradient"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**EDIT:**

I have managed to fix bottom navigation view, what I did is put CoordinatorLayout as the root for each fragment's layout and then applied `fitsSystemWindows=true` to CoordinatorLayout and to the first child as well. But still I am getting issue with title in the toolbar.